# Selenium grid on MAC not support skype web

Tags: selenium, safari, selenium-grid, skype, remotewebdriver

I have setup with MAC (Sierra 10.12.2) that ran selenium grid (3.6.0) and I tried to automate Skype Web chat on Safari (10.0.2).
When the browser opens via RemoteWebDriver I get a message after login from skype that the "site does not support this browser".
When I do it manually on the MAC the chat opens as expected and I can chat.

What can be the problem?

Comment: They might be detecting that you are running selenium

Comment: How? this is the same browser version, same configuration

Comment: I know how one detects Chrome and Firefox but not sure on Safari

Comment: How? by driver exe?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506961/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-geckodriver/46510374#46510374